# Amplify makes `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400` error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-amplify

I got this error with Amplify, I finished the build tho.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
manifest.json:1
```

This system can work in the local environment. Package.json script of the local env is this.

```
  .......
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "format": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix --ignore-path .gitignore ."
  },
  .......
```

My amplify.xml is below.

```
version: 1
frontend:
    phases:
        preBuild:
            commands: 
                - nvm install 14.15.0
                - nvm use 14.15.0
                - yarn install
        build:
            commands: 
                - nvm install 14.15.0
                - nvm use 14.15.0
                - node -v
                - yarn run build
    artifacts:
        baseDirectory: public
        files:
            - '**/*'
    cache:
        paths:
            - 'node_modules/**/*'
```

The screen is totally brank.

[image]

Is there anyone who has the same trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and after spending hours troubleshooting, it turned out to be an Amplify CI/CD build configuration problem.

While connecting the repository to the Amplify app, you are prompted to edit the build settings in the amplify.yaml file. For whatever reason, the default value for `baseDirectory` is set to `public`.

Download the file, place it in the repository root, and change:

```
artifacts:
  baseDirectory: public
```

to

```
artifacts:
  baseDirectory: build
```

Commit, push, reconnect the branch and it should work.